# Rendering two nested objects

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which has 2 props (Artist, tracks) coming from parent. I am trying to render tracks with artist.
Artist: details of selected artist (more than one)
Tracks: Top tracks of these artists in nested arrays

```
import React from 'react';
const ArtistTracks = ({ artists, tracks }) => {

    if (!artists) return null;

    console.log('ArtistTracksComponenet', artists, tracks)

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Your Favourite Artists</p>
            {
                artists.map((artist, i) => {
                    const { images, name, followers, genres } = artist.items[0];

                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <h3>{name}</h3>
                            <p>{followers.total} Followers</p>
                            <p>{genres.join(', ')}</p>
                            <img
                                src={images[0] && images[0].url}
                                alt='artist-profile'
                                style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                    borderRadius: 100,
                                    objectFit: 'cover'
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
            {
                tracks[0].map((track, j) => {
                    const { name, album, preview_url } = track;

                    return (
                        <div
                            key={j}
                            className='track'
                        >
                            <img
                                src={album.images[0].url}
                                alt='trackImage'
                                className='track-image'
                            />
                            <p className='track-text'>{name}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )

}

export default ArtistTracks;
```

I am getting following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't checked whether tracks are provided.

Comment: Yes these are present. Fetching those through API

Comment: If you remove tracks mapping part then console shows the saved arrays for tracks. 0: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: then provide details of the error - there are only 2 lines with map function: artists and tracks, artists are validated and tracks are not.

Comment: Also check should it be tracks[0].map ??  or tracks.map

Comment: It has more than one nested array but currently I am trying to render only one.

Comment: then provide more details on the context and where exactly error occurred - reactjs in debug shows those details.